# Provide a list of colours for the points of ListPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

I want to colour the points in a `ListPlot` with a list of colours, i.e. something like

```
data = Table[Cos[x]^2, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}];
colourData = Table[Cos[x]^2, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}];
colours = (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#] &) /@ colourData;
ListPlot[data,Joined->True (* Something like PlotStyle -> colours*)]
```

And I want an output that looks like this

[image]

Comment: Your data can be generated as `data = Cos[Range[0, 10, 0.1]]`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I have something...

```
data = Table[Cos[x]^2, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}];
colourData = Table[Cos[x]^2, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}];
colours = (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#] &) /@ colourData;
ListPlot[data, ColorFunction -> (Blend[colours, #] &), Joined -> True]
```

[image]

This can be used when the data and colourData are different

```
data = Table[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10, 0.1}];
colourData = Table[Cos[x]^2, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}];
colours = (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#] &) /@ colourData;
ListPlot[data, ColorFunction -> (Blend[colours, #] &), Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This question is well covered in `ListPlot`'s documentation on `ColorFunction`.

```
data = Table[Cos[x]^2, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}];
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

gets you

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't answer the question. This method only allows us to use the y values as data for the colour function. Not an arbitrary function, or an arbitrary list of colours.

Answer (score 0):

Since `data` and `colours` have the length, you can also post-process `ListPlot` output to inject `VertexColors -> colours` into the `Line` object:

```
data1 = Table[Cos[x]^2, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}];
data2 = Table[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10, 0.1}];
colourData = Table[Cos[x]^2, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}];
colours = (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#] &) /@ colourData;

ListPlot[data1, Joined -> True] /. Line[x_] :> Line[x, VertexColors -> colours]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[data2, Joined -> True] /. Line[x_] :> Line[x, VertexColors -> colours]
```

[image]